# can not print hex of truncated value

Tags: floating-point, cout, truncate

I want the float to be converted to a int and displayed in hex value.
this works: `cout << hex << 15;`, but this doesn't:

```
int main(){
    float f = 15.9;
    cout << hex << (trunc(f));
}
```

The output displayed is just 15.
Am I doing something incorrect?

Comment: did you ever read [`std::hex` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex)? It says `Modifies the default numeric base for integer I/O`? And your question is unclear. Do you want to print the underlying bit pattern of the float, or do you want the hexfloat (similar to [`%a` in `printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf))?

Comment: `trunc` returns a `double`, and `hex` has no effect on conversion of `double` values. If you know the result fits in an `int`, you can use `std::cout << std::hex << (int) std::trunc(f);`, and of course you can use wider integer types as appropriate.

Comment: Okay, the last comment worked. I still fail to understand why `trunc()`, which is basically used to get rid of decimal values, will return a `double` type?